# In ngStyle vs ngClass, why doesn't ngStyle work without square brackets, but ngClass does?

Tags: html, css, angular

I was playing around to understand the difference between one-way binding and Interpolation, and found that for `ngClass` the two seem to be equivalent, but for `ngStyle`, I couldn't get it to work using Interpolation (only Binding worked). Please see the following StackBlitz: https://angular-a6cvfb.stackblitz.io for a live example.

None of the `ngStyle` syntax' below that are commented out worked for me. Did I miss something? Many thanks!

{Note: Everything that's commented out is meant to be that way, otherwise it breaks the code}.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
            <button style="background-color: yellow">Button</button> <br/><br/>
            -- ANGULAR DIRECTIVES -- <br/>
            <label>Foo:</label>
            <input value="Foo" [ngClass]="styleClass"/>

            <label>Bar:</label>
            <input value="Bar" [ngStyle]="styleObj" />

            <label>Foo:</label>
            <input value="Foo" ngClass="{{styleClass}}"/> <br/>

            <!--label>Bar:</label> 
            <input value="Bar" ngStyle="{{styleObj}}" />

            <label>Bar:</label> 
            <input value="Bar" ngStyle="{{styleStr}}" />

            <label>Bar:</label> 
            <input value="Bar" ngStyle="{'visibility': 'hidden'}" /--><br/>
<br/><br/>
            -- WITHOUT ANGULAR DIRECTIVES -- <br/>
            <label>Bazz:</label>
            <input value="Bazz" class="{{styleClass}}" />

            <!--label>Bazz:</label>
            <input value="Bazz" style="{{styleStr}}" />

            <label>Bazz:</label>
            <input value="Bazz" style="{{styleObj}}" /-->            

            <label>Buzz:</label>
            <input value="Buzz" style="visibility: hidden" />
            `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }
            .hide{visibility:hidden}`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  styleClass: string = "hide";
  styleObj={'visibility': 'hidden', 'width': '60%'};
  styleStr="'visibility': 'hidden'";

}
```

Comment: you need use `[ngStyle]="variable"` where, e.g. `variable={"background-color":"red"}` (see that if a property has a "-" you need put the property between quotes-. or `style={{myvariable}}`. Another ways are `[ngStyle]="{'background-color':color}">` or `[style.background-color]="color"`

Answer (score 0):

Both property binding and string interpolation works for `ngClass/[ngClass]` as `ngClass` accepts a string, and

interpolation converts anything that's not a string to a string.

String interpolation doesn't work for `ngStyle` because it accepts an object. You'll have to use property binding for ngStyle.